# Leaflet change circle marker color based on text field

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet, geojson

I have circle markers  on my leaflet map using the below code which all works fine.

However I want to show the markers in a different color based on the attribute field named 'stype'.

Any help or guidance on how I can achieve this?

```
        function siteslabels (feature, layer){
        layer.bindPopup("<p class='info header'>"+ 
        "<b>" + feature.properties.SITE + "</b>" + 
        "</br>" + feature.properties.Address1 +
        "</br>" + feature.properties.stype +
        "</p>");
        };


        var geojsonMarkerOptions = {
            radius: 8,
            fillColor: 'green',
            color: 'black',
            weight: 1,
            opacity: 1,
            fillOpacity: 0.8
        };

        L.geoJson(sites, {
            pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
                return L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions);
            },
            onEachFeature: siteslabels
        }).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 5):

Got it sorted. Here is my code

```
    <script>    
        <!-- long and lat for UK & Zoom level for whole of UK  -->
        var map = L.map('map',{ center:[54.038486, -1.948915], zoom: 5});

        L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        }).addTo(map);



        <!-- LAYERS/SITES -->
        <!-- LAYERS/SITES POP UP CONTENT-->
        function siteslabels (feature, layer){
        layer.bindPopup("<p class='info header'>"+ 
        "<b>" + feature.properties.SITE + "</b>" + 
        "</br>" + feature.properties.Address1 +
        "</br>" + feature.properties.stype +
        "</p>");
        };

        <!-- LAYERS/SITES POP UP COLOUR CIRCLE MARKERS->
        function getColor(stype) {
          switch (stype) {
            case 'POP':
              return  'orange';
            case 'Regen':
              return 'green';
            case 'LLU':
              return 'blue';
            case 'Colo':
              return 'purple';
            case 'DMSU':
              return 'blue';
            default:
              return 'white';
          }
        }

        <!-- LAYERS/SITES ADD LAYER->
        L.geoJson(sites, {
            pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
            return new L.CircleMarker(latlng, {radius: 8, 
                                                fillOpacity: 1, 
                                                color: 'black', 
                                                fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.stype), 
                                                weight: 1,});
            },
            onEachFeature: siteslabels
        }).addTo(map);


    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the [Leaflet GeoJSON tutorial](http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/) again, `pointToLayer` option section.

If you render your points as CircleMarkers, you can easily set their `style` to use different colours.

If you stick with Markers, you have to provide custom Icons. You can look for [marker plugins](http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#markers--renderers), e.g. [Leaflet.Extra-Markers](https://github.com/coryasilva/Leaflet.ExtraMarkers).